# SDK Mercado Pago en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mercadopago, sdk

Estoy trabajando con CodeIgniter y necesito agregar el SDK de Mercado Pago, la situción es que no he logrado como hacer que CI me permita trabajar en ella, actualmente tengo la SDK en mi carpeta `/libreries` y yo en mi constructor intengo agregar la SDK de la siguiente forma:

`require_once('application/libraries/MercadoPago/SDK.php');`

y me lanza un error cuando la quiero usar: `$payment = new MercadoPago\Payment();`

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Class 'MercadoPago\Payment' not found

Filename: controllers/Pagos.php
```

Alguien podría ayudarme. Graicas

Comment: https://github.com/jonymusky/sdk-codeigniter-mercadopago Hola amigo, en el link que deje arriba esta la librería de mercadopago ya integrada a un proyecto de Codeigniter, de base te ofrece obtener el ACCESS_TOKEN, no tiene casi nada de documentación pero espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, lo lograste solucionar?

Comment: Debes instalar MercadoPago usando composer.